# How to make slow motion for Particles hair?

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I want to make quick turn of character's head with slow motion. I'm making animation at 24 fps & I don't want to remake it at 60 fps. Is there any way to do slow motion for Particles hair while animating?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

## Option # 1

You can bake your hair particles system, go to the timeline, and stretch/extend the keyframes to make them slow motion. This basically can be done if you first animate your monkey rotation fast (make the keyframes closer together) and then after baking your hair particles system animation, extend/stretch the keyframes in the timeline to fit your ideal slow-mo length (on both the monkey rotation and hair keyframes).

## Option # 2

You can play with these settings in the hair dynamics, such as the stiffness, weight, and damping.[image]

## Option # 3 (The Best)

Enable the `Advanced` checkbox in the hair particles. Now if you scroll down and go to `Physics` you can decrease or increase the `Timesteps` value to control the speed of your animation.[image]

### How to Keyframe these values:

Hover over the values and press **I** or click the dot icon in front of them:[image]

Comment: The second option, unfortunately, is only suitable if all movement is in slow motion, and not partially, since keyframes can't be set on these values.
As for the first option... where are keyframes for baked particles? I baked hair in fast motion, but in timeline there is only red stripe at bottom, but there are no keyframes for particles themselves. There's keyframes only for monkey.

Comment: @Juliya Should be visible if you check some options, but leave method 1 and 2, check method 3

Comment: @Juliya Keyframes **Can** be set on these values. Just press **I** while hovering over the value box, or just press the dot icon in front of the values to keyframe.

Comment: Change values on Timestep can only if hair hasn't been changed in any way in Particle edit. If some hairstyle is done, then Timestep becomes inactive unfortunately.

Comment: @Juliya Then just use Method 1 and search up some tutorials on youtube on how to view your baked keyframes of hair particles.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find how to bake hair particles to keyframes. I also tried to convert hair to mesh, but instead of animation, I got static object. And I tried to slow down animation through NLA but that doesn't affect on hair either, only on monkey.

Comment: @Juliya then animate the keyframes on the values of method 2?  Other than that I would say, you will have to render at 60 fps to get a smooth slow-mo animation, sometimes the hard way is the only way... Maybe the hair bake could be visible in the graph editor? Or maybe there's an option to apply the bake?

Comment: In Graph editor also doesn't show baked hair keyframes.
And how apply baking? I know that can only be applied in one single pose, not in animation.